# I can't deactivate virtual environment in python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm using VScode on windows, and the VScode terminal.
I installed virtualEnv (with `>>> pip install virtualenv` )and everything was working correctly.
Then I installed git, and after this, I couldn't deactivate the virtual environment and I don't see any errors too!
I use this command:
`MyVirtualEnvName\scripts\deactivate`

my problem is: now I can't deactivate virtualenv and the above command isn't working! how can I deactivate this?

Comment: Do you mean deactivate virtualenv? if you want to deactivate the venv just turn off the terminal session.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 9):

try just `deactivate` in the shell, instead of the path to the deactivate script

Comment: This worked for me, including in `venv`s where there was no native `bin/deactivate` script.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a bug, if u try to deactivate with .\deactivate.bat it doesn't work but with a plain 'deactivate' without quotes, it works.
[click to know more](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/70902)

Comment: Same problem deactivate failing.  And this solutions works.  Who would have guessed that I have to override Powershell's auto expand of 'deactivate' to '.\deactivate.bat' .  +Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Go inside Scripts folder by running cd command.
Then just type deactivate.

It will recognize and will run the deactivate.bat file.